# Announcing WPSE-Question - how to encourage users to create plugins for questions

Tags: discussion

I recently answered a question on WPSE that the author was [kind enough](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113264/add-filter-function-in-media-modal-box) to bundle as a plugin.

I realized that there was no way I would have gone through the trouble of answering this if that was not the case. It's often too much work just getting setup to answer a question.

So the idea behind [WPSE-Question](https://github.com/wycks/WPSE-Question) is that complex (or even easy) questions are able to be downloaded via a plugin the answerer can install. It is not meant to take away from pasting code into WSPE but rather complement it.

The problem is how would we encourage it's use.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd just ask when appropriate.

I find myself sometimes suggesting that someone paste code that I can drop into a dev stack and test but mostly I don't find that it is necessary. I basically just paste into a mu-plugin or Twenty* theme files (until they get too beaten up and I just reinstall).

It seems like only very complicated questions require bundled code and I am not sure how many users here would know how to bundle code into a plugin anyway.

I think I'd be warmer to the idea if the Stack Exchange network had its own github like system or even a pastebin feature. As it is you are looking at having to sell people on at least a couple of ideas, one of which is an external service.